# dpkg:unrecoverable fatal error (files list file for package 'java-common' is missing final newline)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

I am trying to install packages on my linux OS using the command `apt-get install ...`.
The problem is that I get this error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'java-common' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Googling the error (even line by line), the solution SEEMS to be "to download and install missing packages to resolve dependencies" as it was point out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551632/unable-to-install-anything-on-ubuntu-14-10-with-apt-get-says-files-list-file-for). The problem is that when I try to execute `sudo apt-get -f install` I continue to have the same error again and again. Any suggestion? How can I change the packages if I cannot use apt-get?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have solved the problem using the python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python


# 8th November, 2009
# update manager failed, giving me the error:
# 'files list file for package 'xxx' is missing final newline' for every package.
# some Googling revealed that this problem was due to corrupt files(s) in /var/lib/dpkg/info/
# looping though those files revealed that some did not have a final new line
# this script will resolve that problem by appending a newline to all files that are missing it
# NOTE: you will need to run this script as root, e.g. sudo python newline_fixer.py

import os

dpkg_path = '/var/lib/dpkg/info/'
paths = os.listdir(dpkg_path)
for path in paths:
    path = dpkg_path + path
    f = open(path, 'a+')
    data = f.read()
    if len(data) > 1 and data[-1:] != '\n':
        f.write('\n')
        print 'added newline character to:', path
    f.close()
```

After running the script with the command `sudo python name_script.py`, the problem was solved: it seems that some files were corrupted. The solution was proposed [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1319791)

Comment: for those coming here via aol keyword `apt-get newline` indentation if your example off, and last time i checked in python  indentation matters.

Comment: Thank you, this script did the trick. Was upgrading an old Raspberry Pi 4 image from 10 to 11 so it could run on the newer pi 4b hardware.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove that missing file

```
 sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/java-common.list
```

Now you can reinstall this

```
 sudo apt-get install java-common --reinstall
```

Comment: Nope. The problem is that it is IMPOSSIBLE to use `apt-get`. See the question for further details.

Comment: Yeah I know, You have to remove this file then automatically it will work if not then you should run this command also "sudo apt autoremove" and "sudo apt clean"

Comment: this worked for me - it is just a bit difficult to find the right `list` file.

Comment: after deleting the file i just did `apt upgrade` and got the message `dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xxx' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed`

Answer (score 0):

If you get the below error

dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package 'java-common' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Note : java-common is the list name

Solve this using below commands(Modify java-common with your list name)

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/java-common.list

sudo apt-get install java-common --reinstall

sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Comment: nope; it was impossible to use `apt` . If you do not solve it, you cannot use `sudo apt-get install ...`

Answer (score 0):

- sudo dpkg --configure -a
- sudo apt-get -f install  sudo apt-get clean
- sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

**It fixed the problem for me.**

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: What does "sudo apt-get -f install sudo apt-get clean" do?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below command and it worked for me

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```